# BlackBerry issue uploading a video file to a Server ... not all the bytes are being sent from the DataOutputStream

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have an interesting issue that I'm experiencing in my BlackBerry application.  We have small video files on the handset that we want to upload to a service running on our Server using a Http POST and a multipart form.  The sequence is as follows:

1. Get a handle to the video file on the /SDCard/BlackBerry/videos/.MP4
2. Get a handle to the file's InputStream so that we can grab the bytes that we'll need to send over our Http connection's OutputSteam.

Simple, really.  Here's the code (normal error checking / exception handling omitted for clerity):

```
    int bytesRead = 0;
    String boundary = "**********";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 * 64 ];

    InputStream fileIS = file.openInputStream();

    httpCon.setRequestMethod( HttpConnection.POST );
    httpCon.setRequestProperty( "Connection", "Keep-Alive" );
    httpCon.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary );

    DataOutputStream dos = httpCon.openDataOutputStream();
    dos.write( ("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8") );
    dos.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"videofile\"; filename=\"" + myFileName + "\"" + "\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8") );

    while ( (bytesRead = fileIS.read( buffer )) != -1 )
    {
        dos.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
    }

    dos.write( ("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8") );
    dos.flush();

    // From this point we do additional processing and close out our various 
    // Streams we've opened.
```

For some strange reason the Server is not getting all the bytes.  I'll have, for example, a file that has 100,000 bytes but the Server will only get 99,640 of them.  The loss is always a very small amount, but there shouldn't be ANY loss, frankly.

What makes things more interesting is using the handset's browser I an upload the same video files to our Server just fine, and the entire file arrives safely.  But, whne we do it programmatically we always end up missing a small number of bytes, which corrupts the video and makes it unplayable.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?  Would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is that the connection is closed before all data packets are sent. Try adding `Thread.sleep()` after `dos.flush()` (for TESTING purposes only and not as permanent solution) and see check if it changes anything. You could also try using `OutputStream` instead of `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried both the OutputStream and DataOutputStream .... same results sadly.  The Thread test didn't reveal anything additional, but an interesting suggestion - thanks.  What's interesting to me is I DO read in all the bytes (verified) but there's always a small handful of bytes that are not written.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a concrete answer but rather a bunch of ideas:

1. I think that the boundary `**********` you are using is not a valid one. Judging by [RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) (7.2.1 Multipart: The common syntax), **"*"** (asterik) is not a valid character. Try changing the boundary to a different one. **boundary** is formally specified by the following BNF:

   > boundary := 0*69 < bchars > bcharsnospace
   >   bchars := bcharsnospace / " "
   >   bcharsnospace := DIGIT / ALPHA / "'" / "(" / ")" / "+" / "_" / "," /
   >   "-" / "." / "/" / ":" / "=" / "?"
2. Is it possible that the closing boundary itself appears within the encapsulated part? Probably very unlikely.
3. Regarding `dos.write( ("\r\n--" + boundary = "--\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8") )` - is the equal sign in `boundary = "--\r\n"` is a *copy&paste* typo? If it is not, then it can be it.

Comment: The boundary we're using actually works on the Anroid and iOS verions of the app.  And, yes, the "=" equal sign was a typo here - the actual code has it correct (I've gone ahead and fixed it in the description of the problem above - thanks).

Comment: @CirrusFlyer Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: yes, I did manage to figure it out.  Thanks for the follow up.